# BrokeredMessage Automatically Disposed after calling OnMessage()

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, queue, servicebus

I am trying to queue up items from an Azure Service Bus so I can process them in bulk. I am aware that the Azure Service Bus has a ReceiveBatch() but it seems problematic for the following reasons:

- I can only get a max of 256 messages at a time and even this then can be random based on message size.
- Even if I peek to see how many messages are waiting I don't know how many RequestBatch calls to make because I don't know how many messages each call will give me back. Since messages will keep coming in I can't just continue to make requests until it's empty since it will never be empty.

I decided to just use the message listener which is cheaper than doing wasted peeks and will give me more control.

> Basically I am trying to let a set number of messages build up and
>   then process them at once. I use a timer to force a delay but I need
>   to be able to queue my items as they come in.

Based on my timer requirement it seemed like the blocking collection was not a good option so I am trying to use ConcurrentBag.

```
var batchingQueue = new ConcurrentBag<BrokeredMessage>();
myQueueClient.OnMessage((m) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Queueing message");
    batchingQueue.Add(m);
});

while (true)
{
    var sw = WaitableStopwatch.StartNew();
    BrokeredMessage msg;
    while (batchingQueue.TryTake(out msg)) // <== Object is already disposed
    {
        ...do this until I have a thousand ready to be written to DB in batch
        Console.WriteLine("Completing message");
        msg.Complete(); // <== ERRORS HERE
    }

    sw.Wait(MINIMUM_DELAY);
}
```

> However as soon as I access the message outside of the OnMessage
>   pipeline it shows the BrokeredMessage as already being disposed.

**I am thinking this must be some automatic behavior of OnMessage and I don't see any way to do anything with the message other than process it right away which I don't want to do.**

Answer (score 3):

This is incredibly easy to do with `BlockingCollection`.

```
var batchingQueue = new BlockingCollection<BrokeredMessage>();

myQueueClient.OnMessage((m) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Queueing message");
    batchingQueue.Add(m);
});
```

And your consumer thread:

```
foreach (var msg in batchingQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completing message");
    msg.Complete();
}
```

[GetConsumingEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an iterator that consumes items in the queue until the `IsCompleted` property is set and the queue is empty. If the queue is empty but `IsCompleted` is `False`, it does a non-busy wait for the next item.

To cancel the consumer thread (i.e. shut down the program), you stop adding things to the queue and have the main thread call `batchingQueue.CompleteAdding`. The consumer will empty the queue, see that the `IsCompleted` property is `True`, and exit.

Using `BlockingCollection` here is better than `ConcurrentBag` or `ConcurrentQueue`, because the `BlockingCollection` interface is easier to work with. In particular, the use of `GetConsumingEnumerable` relieves you from having to worry about checking the count or doing busy waits (polling loops). It just works.

Also note that `ConcurrentBag` has some rather strange removal behavior. In particular, the order in which items are removed differs depending on which thread removes the item. The thread that created the bag removes items in a different order than other threads. See [Using the ConcurrentBag Collection](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=842) for the details.

You haven't said why you want to batch items on input. Unless there's an overriding performance reason to do so, it doesn't seem like a particularly good idea to complicate your code with that batching logic.

---

If you want to do batch writes to the database, then I would suggest using a simple `List<T>` to buffer the items. If you have to process the items before they're written to the database, then use the technique I showed above to process them. Then, rather writing directly to the database, add the item to a list. When the list gets 1,000 items, or a given amount of time elapses, allocate a new list and start a task to write the old list to the database. Like this:

```
// at class scope

// Flush every 5 minutes.
private readonly TimeSpan FlushDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
private const int MaxBufferItems = 1000;

// Create a timer for the buffer flush.
System.Threading.Timer _flushTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimedFlush, FlushDelay.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);  

// A lock for the list. Unless you're getting hundreds of thousands
// of items per second, this will not be a performance problem.
object _listLock = new Object();

List<BrokeredMessage> _recordBuffer = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
```

Then, in your consumer:

```
foreach (var msg in batchingQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // process the message
    Console.WriteLine("Completing message");
    msg.Complete();
    lock (_listLock)
    {
        _recordBuffer.Add(msg);
        if (_recordBuffer.Count >= MaxBufferItems)
        {
            // Stop the timer
            _flushTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

            // Save the old list and allocate a new one
            var myList = _recordBuffer;
            _recordBuffer = new List<BrokeredMessage>();

            // Start a task to write to the database
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FlushBuffer(myList));

            // Restart the timer
            _flushTimer.Change(FlushDelay.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}

private void TimedFlush()
{
    bool lockTaken = false;
    List<BrokeredMessage> myList = null;

    try
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_listLock, 0, out lockTaken))
        {
            // Save the old list and allocate a new one
            myList = _recordBuffer;
            _recordBuffer = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_listLock);
        }
    }

    if (myList != null)
    {
        FlushBuffer(myList);
    }

    // Restart the timer
    _flushTimer.Change(FlushDelay.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

The idea here is that you get the old list out of the way, allocate a new list so that processing can continue, and then write the old list's items to the database. The lock is there to prevent the timer and the record counter from stepping on each other. Without the lock, things would likely appear to work fine for a while, and then you'd get weird crashes at unpredictable times.

I like this design because it eliminates polling by the consumer. The only thing I don't like is that the consumer has to be aware of the timer (i.e. it has to stop and then restart the timer). With a little more thought, I could eliminate that requirement. But it works well the way it's written.

Comment: The batching is for doing bulk writes to the database which is much faster than writing them as soon as each request comes in. I looked at the BlockingCollection before but I am not sure how to implement my timer logic with it. I need to let the queue build up for one second unless I have 1000 waiting to go then I go ahead and write to the database. I'm also not sure if it solves my garbage collection issue I mentioned. I'll take a look at your code and play with it bit.

Comment: This code has the same issue: BrokeredMessage has been disposed.

Comment: It doesn't like me removing the BrokeredMessage from a separate thread. If I remove it in the same method I add it to the Queue it works fine. The minute I try to remove it from my processing loop the Brokered Message shows up as disposed.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites: I suspect that your message is being disposed by something else. Are you sure it's not being disposed by something in the producer? Neither `BlockingCollection` nor `ConcurrentQueue` make any changes to the items  in the collection. I would suggest putting a breakpoint on the object's `Dispose` method so you can see where it's being killed.

Comment: yes, I'm positive. As soon as I try to pull the message off the queue it disposes. The code in my example is pretty much the whole code sample. If i pull the item off the queue on the OnMessage thread and then call Complete() it works fine. As soon as I do the same thing in my while loop shown in my code example the BrokerMessage is disposed.

Comment: Even when I use a normal List<BrokerMessage> I get the same problem. If I look at the list using the debugger before I set a reference to the message it shows disposed as false. As soon as I set a reference to the item, disposed becomes true.  var item = batchingQueue[0];  item.Complete();

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites: Try that with some disposable object other than `BrokeredMessage`. You should find that they're not disposed by the collection. Something in the behavior of `BrokeredMessage` or the object that creates it is tripping you up. It's not the collection classes.

Comment: yeah it's not the collection. I tried something like  BrokeredMessage theone = null;
        public void HandleIncomingMessage(BrokeredMessage m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queueing message");
            if (theone == null)
            {
                theone = m;
            }
        }   .. but even trying to access this reference outside of the OnMessage pipeline it says the object is disposed. It doesn't like me accessing the method anywhere else.

Comment: I'll still need to test, but your code looks great! If I could just get the foreach (var msg in batchingQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) part to work I'd be golden.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is that you make sure you're not setting the `AutoComplete` option to the [OnMessage overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130197.aspx).

Comment: No there is no auto complete. The code works fine inside OnMessage. It's got to be a thread issue. OnMessage receives the reference to the BrokerMessage. It doesn't let me set a reference to it in the global scope and then try to use it.

Comment: I tried to create my own IDisposable but I can't replicate the problem. My dispose does not get called.

Comment: I am pretty sure at this point OnMessage itself calls Dispose() on the msg that's passed in when it exits. That pretty much makes my whole implementation impossible and forces me to stick with ReceiveBatch. Still trying to find a way to prevent this, but I think it's impossible. I saw another poster on the Microsoft forums who basically said they thought the same thing.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites: You could use the data from the message to create a new object, and store that in your `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: I thought of that but figured it might perform terribly. Are you talking about doing a binary clone? This is a rather slow operation.

Comment: Downvoter: It's customary to supply a comment giving a reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Switching to **OnMessageAsync** solved the problem for me

```
_queueClient.OnMessageAsync(async receivedMessage =>
```

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to Microsoft about the BrokeredMessage being disposed issue on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f1a2d88-757b-4c6d-841f-b674e01e937d/brokeredmessage-being-disposed-when-accessed-from-a-separate-thread?forum=servbus), this is the response:

> Very basic rule and I am not sure if this is documented. The received message needs to be processed in the callback function's life time. In your case, messages will be disposed when async callback completes, this is why your complete attempts are failing with ObjectDisposedException in another thread.
>
> I don't really see how queuing messages for further processing helps on the throughput. This will add more burden to client for sure. Try processing the message in the async callback, that should be performant enough.

In my case that means I can't use ServiceBus in the way I wanted to, and I have to re-think how I wanted things to work. Bugger.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when started to work with Azure Service Bus service.

I have found that method OnMessage always dispose BrokedMessage object. The approach proposed by Jim Mischel didn't help me (but it was very interesting to read - thanks!).

After some investigation I have found that the whole approach is wrong. Let me explain the right way to do what you want.

1. Use BrokedMessage.Complete() method only inside OnMessage method handler.
2. If you need to process message outside of this method that you should use method QueueClient.Complete(Guid lockToken). "LockToken" is property of BrokeredMessage object.

Example:

```
 var messageOptions = new OnMessageOptions {
      AutoComplete       = false,
      AutoRenewTimeout   = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 5 ),
     MaxConcurrentCalls = 1
 };
 var buffer = new Dictionary<string, Guid>();

 // get message from queue 
 myQueueClient.OnMessage(
      m => buffer.Add(key: m.GetBody<string>(), value: m.LockToken), 
      messageOptions // this option says to ServiceBus to "froze" message in he queue until we process it
 );         

 foreach(var item in buffer){
    try {
        Console.WriteLine($"Process item: {item.Key}");
        myQueueClient.Complete(item.Value);// you can also use method CompleteBatch(...) to improve performance
    } 
    catch{
        // "unfroze" message in ServiceBus. Message would be delivered to other listener 
        myQueueClient.Defer(item.Value);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to get the message SequenceNumber then defer the message and add the SequenceNumber the BlockingCollection. Once the BlockingCollection picks up a new item it can receive the deferred message by the SequenceNumber and mark the message as complete. If for some reason the BlockingCollection doesn't process the SequenceNumber it will remain in the queue as deferred so it can be picked up later when the process is restarted. This protects against loosing messages if the process abnormally terminates while there's still items in the BlockingCollection.

```
BlockingCollection<long> queueSequenceNumbers = new BlockingCollection<long>();

//This finds any deferred/unfinished messages on startup. 
BrokeredMessage existingMessage = client.Peek();
while (existingMessage != null)
{
    if (existingMessage.State == MessageState.Deferred)
    {
        queueSequenceNumbers.Add(existingMessage.SequenceNumber);
    }
    existingMessage = client.Peek();
}


//setup the message handler
Action<BrokeredMessage> processMessage = new Action<BrokeredMessage>((message) =>
{
    try
    {
        //skip deferred messages if they are already in the queueSequenceNumbers collection.
        if (message.State != MessageState.Deferred || (message.State == MessageState.Deferred && !queueSequenceNumbers.Any(x => x == message.SequenceNumber)))
        {
            message.Defer();
            queueSequenceNumbers.Add(message.SequenceNumber);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // Indicates a problem, unlock message in queue
         message.Abandon();
    }

});


// Callback to handle newly received messages
client.OnMessage(processMessage, new OnMessageOptions() { AutoComplete = false, MaxConcurrentCalls = 1 });            

//start the blocking loop to process messages as they are added to the collection
foreach (var queueSequenceNumber in queueSequenceNumbers.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
     var message = client.Receive(queueSequenceNumber);
     //mark the message as complete so it's removed from the queue
     message.Complete();                 
     //do something with the message       
}
```