# BrokeredMessage disposed after accessing from different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, servicebus

This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467896/brokeredmessage-automatically-disposed-after-calling-onmessage) but that's confused with talk about batching database updates and still has no proper answer.

In a simple example using Azure Service Bus queues, I can't access a BrokeredMessage after it's been placed on a queue; it's always disposed if I read the queue from another thread.

Sample code:

```
class Program {
    private static string _serviceBusConnectionString = "XXX";

    private static BlockingCollection<BrokeredMessage> _incomingMessages = new BlockingCollection<BrokeredMessage>();
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private static QueueClient _client;

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // Set up a few listeners on different threads
        Task.Run(async () => {
            while (!_cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                var msg = _incomingMessages.Take(_cancelToken.Token);
                if (msg != null) {
                    try {
                        await msg.CompleteAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Completed Message Id: {msg.MessageId}");
                    } catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Message was disposed!?");
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        // Now set up our service bus reader
        _client = GetQueueClient("test");

        _client.OnMessageAsync(async (message) => {
            await Task.Run(() => _incomingMessages.Add(message));
        },
        new OnMessageOptions() {
            AutoComplete = false
        });

        // Now start sending
        Task.Run(async () => {
            int sent = 0;
            while (!_cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                var msg = new BrokeredMessage();
                await _client.SendAsync(msg);
                Console.WriteLine($"Sent {++sent}");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
        _cancelToken.Cancel();

    }

    private static QueueClient GetQueueClient(string queueName) {

        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(_serviceBusConnectionString);
        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName)) {
            var settings = new QueueDescription(queueName);
            settings.MaxDeliveryCount = 10;
            settings.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            settings.EnableExpress = true;
            settings.EnablePartitioning = true;
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue(settings);
        }

        var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(_serviceBusConnectionString);
        factory.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1), maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), maxRetryCount: 100);
        var queueClient = factory.CreateQueueClient(queueName);

        return queueClient;
    }
}
```

I've tried playing around with settings but can't get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question with response from Serkant Karaca @ Microsoft [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f1a2d88-757b-4c6d-841f-b674e01e937d/brokeredmessage-being-disposed-when-accessed-from-a-separate-thread?forum=servbus):

> Very basic rule and I am not sure if this is documented. The received message needs to be processed in the callback function's life time. In your case, messages will be disposed when async callback completes, this is why your complete attempts are failing with ObjectDisposedException in another thread.
>
> I don't really see how queuing messages for further processing helps on the throughput. This will add more burden to client for sure. Try processing the message in the async callback, that should be performant enough.

Bugger.